# Запятая и тире в сложноподчиненном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

В справочнике Розенталя есть такие замечательные слова: "Запятая и тире в сложноподчиненном предложении ставятся в качестве единого знака перед словом, которое повторяется для того, чтобы связать с ним новое предложение (чаще придаточное) или дальнейшую часть того же предложения, например: "Теперь же, судебным следователем, Иван Ильич чувствовал, что все без исключения, самые важные, самодовольные люди, – все у него в руках" (Л. Толстой)". Вместе с тем в справочнике ничего не сказано о том, что происходит, когда сложноподчиненное предложение не заканчивается новым предложением или дальнейшей частью того же предложения, с которыми связано повторяющееся слово. Видоизменим предложение, использованное в качестве примера, следующим образом: "Теперь же, судебным следователем, Иван Ильич чувствовал, что все без исключения, самые важные, самодовольные люди, – все у него в руках(?) и наслаждался своей властью над ними". Не знаю, удалось ли мне сохранить стиль Толстого, но не будем цепляться к словам - будем рассматривать видоизмененное предложение как пунктуационную схему, в которой необходимо восполнить пробел, обозначенный вопросительным знаком. Не откажется ли кто-нибудь мне в этом помочь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Приведенную синтаксическую конструкцию стандартной не назовешь, поэтому попробуем поискать аналоги, например:

(1) «ВСЁ: и этот огонь, и эта вода, и тишина эта, и буря – ВСЁ входило в мою душу и соединялось в мою любовь». Здесь повторяется обобщающее слово.

1. Наше предложение (и еще одно из той же темы) отличается от приведенного тем, что вместо однородного  ряда используется обособленный член, – поэтому вместо двоеточия мы имеем запятую:
   2) Теперь же, судебным следователем, Иван Ильич чувствовал, что ВСЕ БЕЗ ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЯ, самые важные, самодовольные люди, – ВСЕ (БЕЗ ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЯ) у него в руках" (Л. Толстой)". 
   (3) Я знала очень хорошо, что это был МУЖ МОЙ, не какой-нибудь новый, неизвестный человек, а хороший человек, – МУЖ МОЙ, которого я знала, как самоё себя.
2. Эти обороты (и однородный ряд, и обособленный член)  по тематике напоминают вводные конструкции: мы как бы уходим от темы, а потом возвращаемся к ней.  Думаю, что дальнейшие знаки препинания не будут зависеть от этой вставки:
   (4) «Теперь же, судебным следователем, Иван Ильич чувствовал, что ВСЕ БЕЗ ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЯ, самые важные, самодовольные люди, – ВСЕ у него в руках, и наслаждался своей властью над ними".
   Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, которое относится к одному из однородных сказуемых в главном предложении.

Comment: Благодарю за внимание к вопросу, которое побудило Вас провести целое исследование.

Трудность ситуации состоит в том, что рекомендации (или, скорее уж, -ультимативные требования) относительно пунктуации в таких случаях не зафиксированы справочной литературой. Но я, пожалуй, соглашусь с Вами: возразить мне нечего.

Comment: Noir, дело в том, что это задача и так имела частный характер, а ваше расширение темы сделало ее еще более частной. Поэтому вряд ли можно в справочнике найти на нее ответ. Вообще говоря, все правила, которыми мы сталкиваемся, - это кем-то решенные орфографические задачи, которые мы используем в качестве образца.Но нельзя же прорешать абсолютно все задачи, поэтому всегда есть вероятность встретиться с еще не решенной. В этом случае  желательно найти общепризнанный аналог и как-то привязаться к нему. Тогда вы сможете не просто применить свой вариант, но и доказать его правильность другим.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна, т.к. придаточное предложение находится внутри главного. Его необходимо обособить.